# Polars rust equivalent of pl.struct()

Tags: rust, rust-polars

I would like to collect several columns in a dataframe into a struct, but do this in Rust. What is the equivalent of the Python polars.struct() in Rust?

I am new to Rust, rust polars documentation is very difficult for me.

Comment: I found it: https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/polars/prelude/fn.as_struct.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`df.into_struct`](https://docs.rs/polars/latest/polars/frame/struct.DataFrame.html#method.into_struct).

```
use polars::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let df = df!(
        "id" => &[1,2,3],
        "name" => &["John", "Jane", "Bobby"],
        "age" => &[32, 28, 45]
    )
    .unwrap();
    let foo: Series = df.into_struct("StructChunked").into_series();
    println!("{:?}", foo);
}
```

This will print:

```
shape: (3,)
Series: 'StructChunked' [struct[3]]
[
        {1,"John",32}
        {2,"Jane",28}
        {3,"Bobby",45}
]
```

Please note that `into_struct` method is behind `dtype-struct` feature flag.

```
polars = { version = "0.38.1", features = ["dtype-struct"] }
```